# Google search overrides search term with suggested results

Tags: google-search

Searching for my domain name without the `.com` ("weddingspot") used to yield results for my website on the front page.  Now, Google displays results for "wedding site" and my website no longer shows up in any search results.  The user has to explicitly click the "search instead" link to find my site.

Why did this happen and is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not seeing your site in any search results.  All I see is wedding dash spot.  If I type in weddingspot.com, I get redirected to the ww35 subdomain which doesn't load properly.  I also see weddingspot.co.uk ranking if I use verbatim.

Comment: Sorry, my domain name is wedding-spot, but that shouldn't make a difference right?

Comment: I was going to suggest that your entire site was penalized for not working properly, but not if your site isn't the one  having the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No enough search volume for this keyword so Google probably assumes the users search for the much more popular term. This could be related to the latest hummingbird algo change - but not necessarily. There are ways to create fake search volumes which i will not specify here - but try searching regularly from different PC's (or incognito, or clean cookies or use proxy etc.) for your domain name - and clicking "Search instead for" and your own site subsequently - after a while you should get the desired outcome.